# SDK 2.0: Way to get to highcharts directly

Tags: rally

I've tried to do some charting with the SDK 2.0 chart object, but its a new feature and the I don't think the doc has caught up yet.  As such, I'd like to just chart directly into highcharts and skip the Rally Glue for now.  How can I get the right libraries loaded to accomplish the following:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart();
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the highcharts library is only loaded on demand when you create a Rally.ui.chart.Chart and render it.  In the future we may make highcharts directly available.